# Emulator and phone keep runing old versions of code

Tags: android, runtime, emulation

I have a weird situation where the changes I make to my android code are not reflected at runtime. Its like both my phone and emulator are stuck running a previous version. I've tried deleting and reimporting the project, deleting the app from both the phone and emulator, but I cannot fix it. Any ides this is driving me crazy.

```
 [2013-02-23 14:52:58 - EchoFriendly] Android Launch!
 [2013-02-23 14:52:58 - EchoFriendly] adb is running normally.
 [2013-02-23 14:52:58 - EchoFriendly] Performing com.example.echofriendly.LogIn activity launch
 [2013-02-23 14:52:58 - EchoFriendly] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'c' is available     on       emulator 'emulator-5554'
 [2013-02-23 14:52:59 - EchoFriendly] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
 [2013-02-23 14:52:59 - EchoFriendly] Starting activity com.example.echofriendly.LogIn on device emulator-5554
 [2013-02-23 14:53:00 - EchoFriendly] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.echofriendly/.LogIn }
```

Probably related to the statement that the app is already deployed and does not need to reinstall. However, this never happened until today. Not sure what changed.

Comment: Have you done "Clean Project?" Increased version code in manifest? What's your console (not logcat) output when you build/push? Have you tried uninstalling the app on the device/emulator?

Comment: I uninstalled it on the device/emulator I will add console when i run it now

Comment: Try deleting everything in `bin` & `gen` folder & do a rebuild.

Comment: Deleted contents of bin and gen just says cannot find apk now

Comment: Seems your build system is not working. Check if all build path are ok. Also check SDK path. Try restarting eclipse. If none of them works then try to re-setup your SDK/Workspace.

Comment: Also check the `Problems` console for any type of build/other error.

Comment: I fixed it by (1) deleting everything (2) downloading a fresh copy from svn (3) creating a new project in a clean workspace (4) importing the code I downloaded to that project (5) changing the version code in the manifest

Comment: Very good it's fixed. Chances are, your project was corrupt. The Console output would have told you, most likely.

Comment: I read console output. Nothing that looks like it was corrupt. I'm glad its fixed too but man that was a pain in the ass.

Comment: Someone said on this link that:

I fixed this by recreating my project for a freshly created android project in eclipse. This now seems to install the apk and recognise i modified something!

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/LrkjFrR0-gA

Comment: I'm more curious as to what caused this issue. Id hate to keep having to reinstall

Comment: `Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.` is your hint. It means that the app either wasn't changed, or wasn't rebuilt. All sorts of reasons for that, but most often, it's a corrupt project, i.e. `src` folder isn't marked as such.

Comment: Well considering I made changes to it it must have some how been corrupt. Anyway to prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 3):

I have solve this problem by Uninstalling my app from the `settings->application->manage` apps from the emulator .
and then reCompiling it into the same emulator